# Edit and Continue not working in VS 2019 with .net Standard C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a C# project I've been working on since VS 2015 (community used for all versions) and worked fine in VS 2017, and now in VS 2019 debugging does not behave as it has in the past.

The application is multi-threaded, and in the past I could put a breakpoint on a line, edit the line, and continue. The changes would take effect and stop me if the syntax was incorrect.

Now, in VS 2019, it will pause, I can edit, syntax can be correct or not, and hit continue but nothing changes in the output of the application.

Additionally, before if I attempted to type while the program was running, it would pop up a message box that indicated I could not edit while the debugger was running. It no longer does this in 2019.

I compared debug options between the two, they are the same for the settings they both have.

I've asked a few peers and we are all lost.

.net standard 4.6.1/2 and 4.8 (I tried various versions to troubleshoot)